# Getting 405 method not found for Put request

Tags: node.js, axios, put

I am working on put call  that update some data but ut throw me 405 method not found error. But when I tried using post call it work fine. I wanted to it work with put call also.

```
const opts = {
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type',
   httpsAgent: new Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false
        }), //CORS i tried to add 
   Accept: '*/*',
   Authorization: auth ,
   },
   method: 'PUT'  
}

return axios.put(endpoint, parameter, opts)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
   })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

Put call should worked. i tried with post call but that work. I tried changing the headers but no luck.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what you're calling it's impossible to help. Sounds like the endpoint doesn't accept PUT requests.